# Combining jQuery + custom script with async or not?

Tags: javascript, jquery, performance, asynchronous, lazy-loading

When looking to speed up the initial load of one of our websites, we have all our javascript in a combined file, quite large now - about 90kb.
All analysis tools out there keep saying "you should switch to *async* to not have JavaScript block rendering of your webpage".

This is what we have right before the closing body tag today

```
<script src="//ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.11.2/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script src="/js/script.js"></script>
```

Our script depends on jQuery. So, my question is, is it better to have a near 200kb script i.e. jQuery concatenated with our script so we know that jQuery gets loaded before our own script, and have it load asynchronously or is there another way to go about this without involving too many third party solutions like headjs, reactjs etc.

Put in code, is this

```
<script src="/js/combined.js" async></script>
```

better than this

```
<script src="//ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.11.2/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script src="/js/script.js" async></script>
```

Does it help any if we keep jQuery sync, and put our script async or is that dangerous in the sense that we can't know for sure that jQuery is loaded before ours?

Or, as a non-solution, do we just not care about this and focus on other stuff i.e. is it really worth hunting down that last performance gain?

Any insights would be much appreciated.

Comment: @Adergarrd When you say "all our javascript", do you mean for the entire site? E.G more than one page?

Comment: Yes. For many reasons we have the base logic of our app in one, rather large (90kb) js-file. Charts for stats, datetimepickers etc, we have outside of the script and those are loaded on the pages they are needed. They are not the problem. The problem is - how do we achieve async without breaking sequence.

Comment: @Adergarrd is it a horrible idea to loop until (window.jQuery !== undefined) at the top of your custom js file?

Answer (score 0):

A better approach is to use a script loader, such as RequireJS or Head.JS. For example, with Head.JS:

```
<script type="text/javascript" src="//cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/headjs/1.0.3/head.min.js"></script>

<script type="text/javascript">
  head.js(
    "//ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.11.2/jquery.min.js",
    "/js/script.js",

    function() {
      startMyCode();
    }
  );
</script>
```

RequireJS is a bit more powerful in that it doesn't execute script in order but by dependency, but requires you to organise your code in modules (as opposed to Head.JS which you can use without any modifications to your code).

**EDIT**: Actually, maybe better go with [$script.js](http://dustindiaz.com/scriptjs), given that `Head.JS` appears not to be maintained any more. To clarify - what these things do is manage asynchronous loading for your code, then making sure it is executed in proper order when all bits are loaded (either sequentially, as Head.JS does, or in some kind of dependency-graph-based manner).

Comment: Maybe my question wasn't uber clear, but the main gripe we have is to move our scripts to load asynchronously. Your solution still loads synchronously afaik. Thanks still.

Comment: Nope, the only synchronous load is `head.js`, which is really small. Initially I missed that you don't want to involve third-party software, but it is really the best choice here.

Answer (score 0):

If you want to make sure your own script loads after jQuery you can add the *defer* attribute.

Take a look at this:http://www.growingwiththeweb.com/2014/02/async-vs-defer-attributes.html

Comment: defer is the ugly cousin of async as I understand it so... no thanks.